# Triple nested loop where outer and inner loop are dependent on n

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

I am trying to count the exact/total number of iterations these nested for-loops are executed:

```
procedure P (integer n);
 for (i: 1 to n)
  for (j: 1 to 10)
   for (k: n to n+5)
    x := x + 1;
```

I know that the first for loop runs (n-1) times, the second loop runs 10-1 (9) times, thus making the time complexity so far 9(n-1). I know that the the third loop will run n+5-n (5) times, but I am not completely sure because of the n involved. I believe with this calculation added, the total runtime will be 5(9(n-1)) which will translate to O(n). In general, I am wondering if this approach of multiplying the iterations of each loop is a good approach to solving worst case running time and big-Theta estimates. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your calculation is to the point. Irrespective of the value which n takes the third loop will run 6 times , don't be confused about the n .

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: Using pattern matching won't get you far; use a [structured approach](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis) instead. Note that you don't really analyse "time" -- what *exactly* are you counting?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think the question is fine (if not great) because (after reading the reference question) it can be read to ask "is this simplifying view on the general technique valid?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In general, I am wondering if this approach of multiplying the iterations of each loop is a good approach to solving worst case running time and big-Theta estimates.

Basically, yes. But you don't really multiply: As explained [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis) at length, you have *nested sums*. In your case,

$\qquad\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{10} \sum_{k=n}^{n+5} 1$

(if we count the number of assignment operations) is easy to evaluate because the loops do not depend on each other. It *looks* like multiplication here, but if you get things like

```
  for i = 1 to n
      for j = 1 to i
          foo
```

that does not work anymore.

Note that worst-case considerations and asymptotics do not enter the picture here.